# How to extract all children & sub children HTML code from a parent container? Python webscraping

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, containers, weather

I want to scrape a chunk of HTML code and load it locally in a newly created HTML file.

First I have to find the right container in the HTML code. I'm currently using the BeautifulSoup module in python to find the parent container (div):

```
url = 'https://darksky.net/details/52.3673,4.8998/2021-8-8/ca24/en'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
raw_weather_forecast = soup.find('div',class_= "timeline_container")
print(raw_weather_forecast)
```

This however only returns the HTML code of the container plus the children containers, but not the HTML contents of these children containers (which I want to scrape aswell):

```
<div class="timeline_container" id="timeline">
<div class="timeline">
<div class="stripes"></div>
<div class="hour_ticks"></div>
<div class="hours"></div>
<div class="temps"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Example of a part of the HTML code I would like to collect (only one to give a better idea of the problem) (Its a picture because it is quite a lot of code): [HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyjmz.png)

How would I tackle this problem? Is there an efficient way to do this in python?

Thanks in advance!

Luc

PS.
To give you a better idea of why I want to achieve this. When I wake up I want my TV to display the weather forecast in my area. I'm using a raspberry pi with HDMI cec to activate my TV when it's time to get up. I then want it to load and show certain things (like my agenda and the weather forecast of that day) that will aid me at the start of the day.

Comment: Can you add the url from where you are scraping? It would be easy to provide a better answer

Comment: Moreover, the output you are providing, is that correct. Because i guess soup.find does not return an array, instead soup.find_all returns one.

Comment: I added the url @oxsapphir3. You were right, the output was altered by my next bit of code which creates the new html file. I corrected it.

Comment: Thats good. I have posted an answer. I guess it will help you

Answer (score 1):

I you want to again find the childrens inside a parent from a given output, you can just parse the output with the BeautifulSoup functions.

Example:

```
url = 'https://darksky.net/details/52.3673,4.8998/2021-8-8/ca24/en'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

raw_weather_forecast = soup.find('div',class_= "timeline_container")

# If you want to iterate through all the divs, then you can do like this:

for node in raw_weather_forecast.find_all("div"):
    print(node.text)

print(raw_weather_forecast.find("div" , class_="hour_ticks").text)
```

It will give an empty output because there was no text.

Comment: Can I do this in a loop for every child container? Or do I have hard code this for every new child (or node so to say).

Comment: Yeah you can do that in a loop. I am updating the answer with your request.

Comment: Check it out! I have added.

Comment: The hour_ticks container contains several spans which I would like to collect too, as do the other containers. Otherwise this would take many lines of code and may break my code if any of the HTML code inside the parent ('class_ = "timeline_container") container changes.

Comment: You can added nested loops. However, if you think that your code may break, you can add try-except blocks outside of your nested loop.

Comment: Moreover, you can add an if - else and check if the classname of the node is equal to the classname that you want to again nest.

Comment: Alright thanks, I will try this out. Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: Its my pleasure <3